# Display image Batik JSVGCanvas

Tags: java, canvas, svg, batik

I am trying to display an `SVG file` in a `JSVGCanvas` using `Batik`. IN this SVG file there are an image. The thing is that the image is not shown. Instead of that I get an error image. This is my code:

**SVG file**

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<image x="0" y="0" width="150" xlink:href="C:\Absolute\path\to\image" xlink:type="src" height="150"  />
</svg>
```

**JAVA code**

```
File file = new File("C:/absolute/Path/To/File");
    String url = null;
    try {
        url = file.toURL().toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(url);
    JSVGCanvas canvas = new JSVGCanvas();
    canvas.setEnableImageZoomInteractor(true);
    canvas.setSize(500,500);


canvas.setURI(url);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Batik Graphics");
    f.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

**NOTE**
 If the SVG file is openned with the browser, the image is shown correctly.

Comment: I also have tried this, but it doesn`t work either

Comment: OK, I got it. I wrote file:///Absolute/path/to/image (3 slashes instead of 2) and it is working. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Absolute\path\to\image is not a valid href. I guess you want file:///Absolute/path/to/image instead.